# WPF: Progress bar in ListView

Tags: wpf, data-binding, listview, progress-bar

I'm trying to display information from my `ObservableCollection<MyData>` in a `ListView`.  `MyData` has:

```
string Name
string Location
int Progress
```

Using `DataBinding`, I'm able to display the `Name` and `Location` for all the items in my `ObservableCollection<MyData>` in their own column.  But how can I add a `Progress` column with a `ProgressBar` inside?  `Progress` is a percentage.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding PersonList}">  
    <ListView.View> 
        <GridView>  
            <GridViewColumn Width="140" Header="GameName" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Width="140" Header="Progress">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>  
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ProgressBar Maximum="100" Value="{Binding Progress}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                 </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>  
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>  
    </ListView.View>  
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 6):

Your ListView in XAML:

```
<ListView x:Name="DataView">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <Label Content="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                    <ProgressBar Height="20" Width="100" Value="{Binding Path=Progress}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Code-behind:

```
internal class MyData
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Progress { get; set; }
}

...

var items = new ObservableCollection<MyData>();

items.Add(new MyData() { Name = "Some", Progress = 25 });
items.Add(new MyData() { Name = "Another", Progress = 91 });

DataView.ItemsSource = items;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just bind Progress property in MyData to the ProgressBar.Value and set the expected MAX value as the ProgressBar.Maximum for example 50 below

```
<ProgressBar Maximum="50" Value="{Binding Progress}" ..
```

Comment: Where would I find that in my xaml?

<Grid Name="myGrid">
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding PersonList}">
            <ListView.View> 
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="140" Header="GameName" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>