# what is wrong with this sql query to get all files?

Tags: sql-server

```
SELECT User1.NAME,User1.PORT,User1.IP,File1.SIZE,File1.FNAME
```

FROM [User_File],[User1],[File1] WHERE User1.ACTIVE = 'TRUE' AND [User_File].UID= User1.UID AND

[User_File].FID=File1.FID

i'm trying to get all the files of the users that are '"active".
this query return nothing.
pls help!

Comment: It's very hard to read your question (formatting...) and understand what you're asking. Could you add more detail to explain what you're trying to achieve, and what you've attempted so far?

Comment: @galkogeman Not really!

Comment: @galkogeman you can't bind a ProgressBar to a column in the listView. Try to bind the value of the progress to a custom column that display a progress bar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create a property to hold the collection of Downfile objects, for example

```
ObservableCollection<Downfile> downFileList = new ObservableCollection<Downfile>();
```

Then add concrete instances to that list

```
downFileList.Add(new DownFile (...));
```

And finally bind that collection to the items source of the ListView

```
<ListView x:Name="downList" ItemsSource="{Binding downFileList}" />
```

Comment: Here is an example : http://1drv.ms/1zj52uJ. And for progress bar binding i suggest this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1705560/wpf-progress-bar-in-listview